# What's the best way to have users edit specific section of user profile?

Tags: panels, users, entities

I plan on using [Panels module](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) and [Profile2 module](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) to organize and create profile fields.

For example left column of panels will have user picture, user name, bio field, 4 social media link fields.

I'm wondering if there's a way to have users click on the section or field and be able to edit that area rather than one long edit page.

Is QuickEdit module an option for this?